# Show one popover and hide other popovers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have several buttons and I need a popover for each.  When my user clicks on one of them, I want the others to be hidden, so that only one popover is shown. Please help me correct this example:

```js
var mycontent='<div class="btn-group"> <button class="btn">Left</button> <button class="btn">Middle</button> <button class="btn">Right</button> </div>'
```

```js
$('.btn').popover({
    html: true,
    content:mycontent,
    trigger: 'manual'
}).click(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').click(function(e) {
     $('.btn').popover('hide');
});
```

my html:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="" >Popover</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="" >Popover</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/moalla/fsRaN/2/)

Adding something like the code below solved my problem somehow:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
     $('.btn').popover('hide');
});
```

but after clicking twice on each button, it goes wrong!

Comment: if there is something wrong with the way i asked my question plz before giving negative mark leave me a comment to teach me how to ask my next question

Comment: Why isn't `trigger:'focus'` an answer? This automatically hides other popups.

Comment: Look here, I have just answered [Bootstrap popover normalization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635046/bootstrap-3-popover-div-html)

Comment: Look, I have just answered [Bootstrap popover normailzation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635046/bootstrap-3-popover-div-html)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I created one example for my need. I used this code:

```
$('.btn').popover();

$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.btn').not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/moalla/vFDSZ/2/)

... and I corrected the previous [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/moalla/fsRaN/4/).

Comment: note that other popovers tags would not be removed, they will be simply hided

Comment: popover('hide') does remove. Name is misleading.

Comment: As Denis said it's not complete, you should remove it after with $('.btn').not(this).popover('hide').next('.popover').remove()

Comment: problem is that, when i want new one to open, i have to click two times.

Comment: @funky-nd i have the same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: @SizzlingCode i don't remember :(

Comment: any update/solution about this scenario in bootstrap 5 ?

Answer (score 30):

None of the answers I saw previously had dynamic popovers, so this is what I came up with. As some have pointed out, there are issues with popovers causing problems if they aren't removed from the DOM using `.remove()`. I forked [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/fScua/) from the bootstrap website and created [this new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/losmescaleros/zoqvomva/). Dynamic popovers are added using the `selector: '[rel=popover]'` option. When a popover is about to be shown, I call destroy on all the other popovers, then remove the `.popover` content from the page.

```
$('body').popover({
                selector: '[rel=popover]',
                trigger: "click"
            }).on("show.bs.popover", function(e){
                // hide all other popovers
                $("[rel=popover]").not(e.target).popover("destroy");
                $(".popover").remove();                    
            });
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for thinking about dynamic popovers in this solution! Elegant.

Comment: I had to use `$("[rel=popover]").not(e.target).popover("hide");` instead of 
`$("[rel=popover]").not(e.target).popover("destroy");`

Comment: this only works if you change
`$("[rel=popover]").not(e.target).popover("destroy");` to
`$("[rel=popover]").not(e.target).removeData('bs.popover').popover("destroy");`
otherwise you have to click twice on those who were previously open

Comment: @StefanGabos still required me to click twice :'(

Comment: forgot to mention that I am using 3.3.7

Comment: For the latest release, one needs to use 'dispose' instead of 'destroy' method.

Answer (score 30):

The easiest way to do this is to set   `trigger="focus"` in your popover

> Dismiss on next click
>
> Use the focus trigger to dismiss popovers on the next click that the
>   user makes.

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

**Note** - this will mean the popover will hide as soon as you click off of it

Comment: This should be the correct answer. This functionality existed in 2.X ( search focus on http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers ), 3.X ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click ), and the 4.X beta ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#dismiss-on-next-click )

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Just a note: the tabindex is required. It won't work without it.

Comment: More recent version of Bootstrap, which is 4.4.1, recommends using <a> tag instead of <button> tag for popover due to cross browser support. More on that here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/popovers/ . Also it's easy to forget 'tabindex' attribute which is important for data-trigger="focus" to work properly.

Answer (score 10):

This is a quick generic solution that I'm using where you don't need to know what the classes are of the popovers in advance. I haven't tested it super extensively. Also I'm using toggle below as I had some problems with the hide behaving quite differently than the toggle.

```
  var $currentPopover = null;
  $(document).on('shown.bs.popover', function (ev) {
    var $target = $(ev.target);
    if ($currentPopover && ($currentPopover.get(0) != $target.get(0))) {
      $currentPopover.popover('toggle');
    }
    $currentPopover = $target;
  });

  $(document).on('hidden.bs.popover', function (ev) {
    var $target = $(ev.target);
    if ($currentPopover && ($currentPopover.get(0) == $target.get(0))) {
      $currentPopover = null;
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is the best answer & will work in most cases. +1 for using the *.bs.popover events.

Answer (score 5):

Using Bootstrap 3.3.7 I find this solution:

```
var _popoverLink = $('[data-toggle="popover"]');

_popoverLink.on('click', function(){
  _popoverLink.popover('destroy').popover({container: 'body'});
  $(this).popover('show');
});
```

regards.

Comment: doesn't work for me. it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of nul"

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest and elegant way to do this:

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('click', function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').not(this).popover('hide');
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You are taking this too seriously, just close every opened popover before triggering the new one to be opened:

```
// Hide any active popover first
            $(".popover").each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.popover('hide');
            });

//Now Execute your new popover
$('.btn').popover({
                html: true,
                content: mycontent,
                trigger: 'manual'
            }).click(function (e) {
                $(this).popover('toggle');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
```

Comment: Problem with this: once the tooltip is hidden, to show it again it needs 2 clicks

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that worked for me. In my scripts I don't pass vars through the data attribute in the HTML, I prefer the logic in my js files.

```
            $(".vote").popover({
                trigger: " click",
                title: "Attention",
                content: "You must be a member of the site to vote on answers.",
                placement: 'right'
            });

            $('.vote').on('click', function (e) {
                $('.vote').not(this).popover('hide');
            });
```

Comment: If you want to see how I implemented the solution, check out my project that I used the logic: https://github.com/TheRealJAG/Laravel-QuestionAnswer

Answer (score 3):

With the help of "losmescaleros" answer, this works perfectly for me :

```
$('body').popover({
  selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]',
  trigger: "click"
}).on("show.bs.popover", function(e){
  // hide all other popovers
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").not(e.target).popover("destroy");                  
});
```

Without any double click issues.

Comment: `Destroy`: Hides and destroys an element's popover.

Comment: This worked. Spent hours searching and trying different solutions. This one worked for me because it was using `[data-toggle="popover"]`

Comment: Best solution, but instead of destroy I used .popover('hide')

Answer (score 0):

I was having some difficulty using any of the answers posted to solve this issue using bootstrap v3. After some searching I found my primary issue was not setting the proper popover trigger. It should be set as 'manual' as listed in the op's question.

The next step was very simple and gives some better behavior than the solutions I see in the other answers so I thought I would share.

```
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).hasClass('btn')) {
    $(e.target).popover('toggle');
  }

  if(!$(e.target).parent().hasClass('popover')) {
    $('.popover').prev('.btn').not(e.target).popover('toggle');
  }
});
```

This solution gives you the ability to dismiss the popover upon clicking anywhere else on the page including another popover link but allows you to click on the popover itself without dismissing it so that the popover can be accessed by the user for things like copy pasting text.

Hope this helps someone, here is a working fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/hL0pvaty/

p.s. - I am only using the .btn class as the selector in my example because it is used in the op's question. I would recommend using something less generic.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a combinations of approaches I've seen both on this thread and others. My requirements specify that:

- Only one popover should be visible at a time
- A click anywhere outside the popover should dismiss the popover
- The popover should contain a control
- Should not require rebinding the popover event

  ```
      function bindEvents() {

           setupPopupBinding();

           setupPopupDismissal();
      };

      function setupPopupBinding() {
             $('.addSectionItem').popover({
                    html: true,
                    content: function () {
                          return createDropdowns($(this).data('sectionid'))[0].outerHTML;
                    },
                    placement: "right",
                    trigger: "click focus"
             }).on("inserted.bs.popover", function (e) {
                  //initialize dropdown
                  setupSelect2();
             }).on("hide.bs.popover", function (e) {
                   $('.select2-container--open').remove();
             });
      }

      function setupPopupDismissal() {
             $('body:not(.addSectionItem)').on('click', function (e) {
             $('.addSectionItem').each(function () {
             //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
             //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
             if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
             $(this).popover('hide');
             $('.popover').has(e.target).remove();
          }
      });
      });
      }

      function createDropdowns(sectionId: number) {
             var dropdown = $('<div/>')
             .attr('Id', 'sectionPopupWrapper' + sectionId)
             .addClass('popupWrapper')
             .append($('<select/>').addClass('sectionPopup'))
             .append($('<button/>').addClass('btn btn-primary btn-xs')
             .attr('data-sectionid', sectionId)
             .text('Add'));

      return dropdown;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-trash-o DeleteRow" id=""></i>1</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-trash-o DeleteRow" id=""></i>2</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-trash-o DeleteRow" id=""></i>3</li>
</ul>

// Close other popover when click on Delete/Open new popover - START //
     $('.DeleteRow').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
     });
 // Close other popover when click on Delete/Open new popover - END//
```

Answer (score 0):

When an icon is clicked and has open the corresponding popover then it has a value that begins with "popover*" called aria-describedby.

So you find this icons and trigger click on them but not on the icon which is clicked now.

```
$('.icon-info').click(function(){
    $(".icon-info[aria-describedby*='popover']").not(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a few comments point out, calling `popover('hide')` to hide any displayed popovers results in having to click twice to get the popover back if you want to see it again.

I think this is caused by a bug introduced sometime after v3.2 with the introduction of the `inState.click` property.

`Tooltip.prototype.toggle` modifies this property in v3.4 for example. [(Source)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/4c547f2175b9a05aa43551f6927da83fe249ce42/js/tooltip.js#L467)

`Tooltip.prototype.hide/show` should also modify it but does not. [(Source)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/4c547f2175b9a05aa43551f6927da83fe249ce42/js/tooltip.js#L313)

So if you call `popover('hide')` the `inState.click` will remain `true`. Then when you click on the trigger element, it will call `Tooltip.prototype.toggle` which still thinks the popover is displayed and negates the `click` property because it's trying to hide it.  Another click is then required to show it.

I see 2 solutions here. Use `toggle` rather than `hide/show` or fix the bug:

A one line fix seems to correct this issue (at least in v3.4):

```
  Tooltip.prototype.hide = function (callback) {
    this.inState.click = false; //add this line
```

This is based on my limited understanding of popover/tooltip functionality. Hopefully it doesn't introduce other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. I had the same problem. This is the best solution I worked out for it. Add this code in place of Bootstrap's popover initialization code.

```
function popoverInit() {
    // Get all of the popover links/btns
    let popoverList = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bs-toggle='popover']");
    // Loop through each popover link/btn
    popoverList.forEach(popoverItem => {
        // Initiate bootstrap.popover() and set it to be triggered manually
        let popover = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverItem, {
            trigger: "manual"
        });
        // Add click event to popover links/btns
        popoverItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
            // Once one popover has been clicked open, start capturing their "content wrapper divs" into an array (there aren't any until one has been clicked)
            let popoverWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".popover.show");
            let wrappersArr = Array.from(popoverWrappers);
            popover.show(); // On first popover clicked, show it
            // Loop through each popover body
            wrappersArr.forEach(wrapper => {
                let wrapperToDeleteId = wrapper.getAttribute("id"); // Get the ID of the previously opened popover body
                // If the item's id matches, then remove it from the DOM, else toggle the current one open
                if ((wrapper.id = wrapperToDeleteId)) {
                    wrapper.remove();
                } else {
                    popover.toggle();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

popoverInit();
```