# How can I hide popovers on page when clicking a new one?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3, I have created multiple popovers on my page and are shown by clicking on them.  How can I hide all currently open popovers before opening the new one clicked on?  Currently when I click on "Item 1" it opens and closes just fine, but if "Item 1" is open and then I click on "Item 2", now both are open.

Example code:

```
Item 1:<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Unavailable">Unavailable</a>
<br />
Item 2:<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Unavailable">Unavailable</a>

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      html: true,
      content: '<removed html to keep it short>',
      title: 'Unavailable',
      trigger: 'click',
      animation: true
  })
})
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to show us whats happening/aid us in helping figuring out the solution to your issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap: show one popover and hide other popovers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150163/bootstrap-show-one-popover-and-hide-other-popovers)

Comment: isherwood, it appears to be the same question, but Brad's answer was better than those answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers):

> **Dismiss on next click**
>
> Use the focus trigger to dismiss popovers on the next click that the user makes.

So, change your trigger to `focus` instead of `click`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't fully understand what that meant, but makes sense now.