# Bootstrap 3 - Popover div html

Tags: bootstrap-table, bootstrap-popover

I based in this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hL0pvaty/

But the popover must contain a html div , therefore, what I want is a mixture between the first and the second link:
https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/bootstrap-3-popover-with-html-content/

This is the js code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".show-popover-div", function (e) {
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
            return clone;
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This works, but forces me to make double-click the link, and it should work with just one click.

One thing, this example is very ok, but i need apply some changes, i want the same, but from a link, i open one modal window that loaded a json file,

The json file have a image links that open the popover, as you have shown me (i  am using bootstrap-table for to load the json file)

This is the json file:

```
[
    {
        "col1": "<a href='#'>13560431</a>",
        "col2": "<a href='#' class='popup-window' data-placement='left'><img src='img/ico_add_td.png' /></a>"
    },
    {
        "col1": "<a href='#'>44560422</a>",
        "col2": "<a href='#' class='popup-window' data-placement='left'><img src='img/ico_add_td.png' /></a>"
    }
]
```

This the js code for to load json file with bootstrap-table:

```
$("#table-alert2").bootstrapTable({
    url: 'data-table-alert2b.json',
    columns: [{
        field: 'col1'
    }, {
        field: 'col2'   
    }, ]
});
```

This is the div link html and modal window:

```
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: #ccc; text-align: center;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalReguOpor">
   <div>Regulatorias</div>
   <div>7</div>
</div>      
<!-- Modal regulatorias -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModalReguOpor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table id="table-alert2" class="table table-striped"></table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input id="cancel" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cerrar" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could you help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a code for normalization bootstrap popovers:

- multiply popovers
- popovers with close button
- close by click outside the popover
- popover with custom HTML

Check out the [demo](http://olgayellowflowers.github.io/code/html-bootstrap-popover/)

Source code [download](http://olgayellowflowers.github.io/code/html-bootstrap-popover/html-bootstrap-popover.zip)

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

$('.popup-window').popover({
    html: true,
    title : '<button type="button" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;.popup-window&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popup-content').html();
    }
}).click(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
    $('.popup-window').not(this).popover('hide');

    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.popup-window').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });

});
```

and html

```
        <div class="actions">

        <!-- Action  -->
        <div class="popup-window" data-placement='left'>
            <i title='Share' class="btn-popup fa fa-share-alt"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-content hide">
            <div class="socialShare">
                <label class="form-group">Share:</label>
                <div class="well">
                    <a title="Share on twiiter" target="_blank" href="#">
                        <i style="font-size: 40px;" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a title="Share on facebook" target="_blank" href="#">
                        <i style="font-size: 40px;" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Action -->
        <div class="popup-window" data-placement='bottom'>
            <i  title='Respond To Review' class="btn-popup fa fa-share-square-o"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-content hide">
            <div class="">
                <label class="form-group">Respond To Review:</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control">Great song BRO!</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary respondToReview width100" onclick="respondToReview(this);">Post Response</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
```

and css

```
   .actions .popover-content {
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
.actions .popup-window,
.action-link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #2fa0e5;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.actions .popup-window:hover,
.actions .popup-window:focus,
.action-link:hover,
.action-link:focus {
    opacity: 0.85;
}
.action-link:last-child,
.actions .popup-window:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.btn-popup.fa {
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.actions .popover-title {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    float: right;
}
.actions .popover-content .form-group:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.actions .popover-content .well {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.actions .popover-content .well a {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
///HTML 
      <div id="btnSave_popover" class="div-popover">
    ///HTML content here
      </div>


///Css classes for popover
        .div-popover {
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 8px !important;
            box-shadow: -1px 1px 9px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 7px 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 250px;
            bottom: -4px;
        }

        .div-popover:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -10px;
            left: 175px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 25px 25px 0;
            border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
        }
  .hidden {
    display: none !important;
  }
///JQuery for button click 
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            if ($("#btnSave_popover").hasClass("hidden")) {
                $("#btnSave_popover").removeClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $("#btnSave_popover").addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
```