# Popover doesn't work at first time hover on icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

below is the code used to load pop up on hover it doesn't load on first hover .it work fine on second hover

```
<i id="weaCarrierIcon" class="fas fa-info-circle fa-lg infoIcon weaCarrier-infoicon" ng-click="weaCarrierPopover()" ng-mouseover="weaCarrierPopover()" data-toggle="popover" data-content="{{model.weaCarrierPopover}}"></i>
                        

$scope.weaCarrierPopover = function () {
            $('#weaCarrierIcon').popover({ placement: 'bottom', trigger: 'hover', html: true, delay: { show: 50, hide: 400 } });
        };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show one popover and hide other popovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150163/show-one-popover-and-hide-other-popovers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.weaCarrierPopover = function () {
$('#weaCarrierIcon').popover({ placement: 'bottom', trigger: 'hover', html: true, delay: { show: 50, hide: 400 } }).popover('show');
};

Adding .popover('show') fixed the issue.